# Eigen/Dense not found with installation of Shogun

Tags: python, shogun

I'm currently trying to install [Shogun](http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/page/home/) a machine learning toolbox and to use it with Python. I'm facing a problem with the Eigen3 package, when I try `sudo port install shogun` it gives me this error (log file):

```
:info:configure Error: Eigen3 not found
...
:info:configure ./configure-11619-9060.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'Eigen/Dense' file not found
:info:configure #include <Eigen/Dense>
:info:configure          ^
```

I've seen that some people say that changing to

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"
```

solve their problem, but I don't have access to this file, so I can't change it.

And if I type

```
$ ls /opt/local/include/eigen3/
Eigen                   unsupported
signature_of_eigen3_matrix_library
```

it gives me this, so I don't know what to try, any idea?

**EDIT** : I used [this formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/shogun.rb) with these custom 2 lines

```
args = std_cmake_args + [
...    
"-DBUNDLE_EIGEN=ON",
"-DPythonModular=ON",
...
]
```

Now it does not report any error, but it does not recognize shogun

```
$ ipython
In [1]: import shogun
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0add07018436> in <module>()
----> 1 import shogun

ImportError: No module named shogun

In [2]: import modshogun
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0add07018436> in <module>()
----> 1 import modshogun

ImportError: No module named modshogun
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add one of the following options to your cmake call to resolve this:

Either get eigen in you include directory

```
    -DEIGEN_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/local/include/eigen3/
```

or you can use

```
   -DBUNDLE_EIGEN=ON
```

to make shogun download the eigen3.

Comment: the eigen problem is solved but shogun is not recognized (i've edited my question)

Comment: `ImportError: No module named modshogun` I didn't find the `_moshogun.so` file, so maybe it doesn't know where to find it

Comment: it might be that you have to set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to the location where _modshogun.so did get installed.

Comment: but `sudo find /usr/ -name "modshogun.so"` doesn't give any result, did the installation fail ?

Comment: -name '*modshogun.so'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98684/discussion-between-dooms-and-soeren-sonnenburg).